# Web-Service: JAX-WS, CXF, WSDL... What's that all about?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, cxf

Sorry fot his newbie question. But I really need a start on this one.
I want to access a webservice in my Java EE project. This webservice offers a WSDL file. So I understand I can use this to build Java code from it to access the web service.
Now I read that Apache CXF is a good framework that I can use. But what's the difference to JAX-WS?

Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JAX-WS is a Specification (provided by <strike>Sun</strike> Oracle) to defining Web Services by use of Annotations.

Apache CXF is a framework that implements JAX-WS to generate Web Services Definitions and Java Proxy (from a Web Service Definitions)

Apache Axis 2 is also a framework that now supports JAX-WS (up to JAX-WS 2). It's an improvement from Apache Axis. CXF supports up to JAX-WS 1.2.

Brief tutorial can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html).

Answer (score 5):

JAX-WS is an API (or specification) and CXF is an implementation of that API. There is also a reference implementation available [here](https://jax-ws.java.net/)

Comment: Apache CXF has a similar explanation for the relationship: [Why CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/why-cxf.html)

Answer (score 3):

CXF is good but you don't need it to solve your problem.  You can use [wsimport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html), which comes as part of the JDK, to generate classes from the WSDL to access the web service.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, but with CXF or Metro you are getting an implementation web services stack and with that are extra features beyond the JAX-WS api.  That is why JAX-WS RI also has more features available than just JAX-WS.

I think this article explains this very well in detail.

http://www.predic8.com/axis2-cxf-jax-ws-comparison.htm